# How can I redirect user to the payment gateway after placing order in magento 2?

Tags: checkout, payment-methods, payment, payment-gateway, magento2.1.5

I am creating my own payment method which should redirect user to the payment gateway of a bank after placing order. How can I do it?

Comment: Please create sales order place after observer and do your redirection. First that order will be in pending status after the payment you need to change that payment to processing.

Comment: Did you find the perfect solution to it ? If yes please let me know as the one i have created doesn't pass the default TnC value to the "set-payment-information"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the observer code to redirect to that payment gateway.

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{ 
    $orderId = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
    $base_url = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order') ->load($orderId[0]);
    $payment = $order->getPayment();


    $method = $payment->getMethodInstance();
    $methodTitle = $method->getTitle();

    $order_data= $order->getData();
    $status = $this->checkoutSession->getLastOrderStatus();

      $increment_id = $order_data['increment_id'];
      $redirect = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http');
      $redirect->setRedirect($base_url.'custompayment/index/redirect/id/'.$increment_id.'');
      return;

}
```

My Controller having load layout and render layout only please find my phtml file for that controller it'll auto submit and redirect to payment gateway,

`<form action="<?php echo $this->getModeurl();?>" id="custom_payment" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="pay" />
    <input type="hidden" name="currency" value="<?php echo $this->getOrderdetails('order_currency_code');?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="version" value="2.0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name_<?php echo $i ?>" value="<?php echo $item['name'] ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_description_<?php echo $i ?>" value="<?php echo $item['description'] ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_quantity_<?php echo $i ?>" value="<?php echo round($item['quantity']) ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_amount_<?php echo $i ?>" value="<?php echo $item['price'] ?>" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="merchant" value="<?php echo $this->getMerchant();?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ref_id" value="<?php echo $this->getOrderdetails('increment_id');?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="delivery_charge" value="<?php echo $this->getOrderdetails('shipping_amount');?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="tax_amount" value="<?php echo $this->getOrderdetails('tax_amount');?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="total_amount" value="<?php echo $this->getOrderdetails('grand_total');?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="str_url" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="http://127.0.0.1/payment/smoovpay/index/response" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_url" value="http://YourWebSite" />
    <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="<?php echo $this->getSignatureHash();?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="signature_algorithm" value="sha1" />
    <h3>Please wait we are redirecting to Smoovpay.....</h3>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var paymentform = document.getElementById('custom_payment');
    window.onload = paymentform.submit();
//]]>
</script>`

Comment: thanks for your answer. It seems like you are redirecting user to my own stores's url How am I supposed to communicate with payment gateway's API.

Comment: For that i written code in my own controller ,  I don't know which payment your using. I did like it'll redirect to my own controller in that controller i formed payment params that one redirect to payment gateway

Comment: Could you please share a small snippet of your controller code.

Comment: Check the update above, Create corresponding block and controller i just added phtml file for redirection. Still have clarification means tell me

Comment: Thank you I checked it. Have you done payment method in which credit card info are entered in checkout page?

Comment: Mine in hosted payment not API. It will redirect to third party payment site

Comment: I got it, it redirects to third party payment site. thanks.

Comment: Yes please mind with the payment state while redirect it'll be in pending status , After the payment only you need to change that order to processing.

Comment: Okay, I'll handle it.

Comment: I have posted a question may be you can help. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/204624/get-order-in-observer-after-placing-order