# Get order in observer after placing order

Tags: magento2, orders, event-observer, order-status, onestepcheckout

I have created an observer to capture the order after placing it for event <kbd>checkout_onepage_controller_success_action</kbd> as follows:

```
<?php
namespace Magento\SamplePaymentGateway\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class ProcessGatewayRedirect implements ObserverInterface
{
    private $storeManager;
    protected $_checkoutSession;

    public function __construct(
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession   
    ) {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    { 
        $orderId = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
        $base_url = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order') ->load($orderId[0]);
        $payment = $order->getPayment();


        $method = $payment->getMethodInstance();
        $methodTitle = $method->getTitle();

        $order_data= $order->getData();
        $status = $this->_checkoutSession->getLastOrderStatus();

        $increment_id = $order_data['increment_id'];
        $redirect = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http');
        $redirect->setRedirect($base_url.'custompayment/index/redirect/id/'.$increment_id.'');
        echo 'oid' ;var_dump($orderId);
        var_dump($base_url);
        echo 'method' ;var_dump($method);
        echo 'mettitle' ;var_dump($methodTitle);
        echo 'status' ;var_dump($status);
        return;

    }
}
```

I'm getting all the real data except order id. For example, orderId dumped by this code is 31 whereas the order id as seen in backend is 45. I ran the test for second time and orderId dumped is 32 and in the backend it is 46. What is happening here? How to get the actual order id?

Comment: Two time order is created right?

Comment: No problem is not two order created at once.

Comment: You dumped order id , but the new order id is created in backend right?

Comment: Yes, I dumped order id, but the id shown at backend is greater than the order id displayed by this code.

Comment: For this two times that observer will call  so order will create two times. So you need to load the old quote in below you see that response.php file i loaded old quote and changed the status to processing. After that in observer i checked whether the status is processing means it will redirect to success page. Pending means it will create order i handled in observer check that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Response controller after the payment success it will come to this controller load the success page.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Pay.nl All rights reserved.
 */

namespace Jed\Custompayment\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Payment\Helper\Data as PaymentHelper;
use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository;
use Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository;
use Paynl\Error\Error;

/**
 * Description of Redirect
 *
 * @author Andy Pieters <andy@pay.nl>
 */
class Response extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Paynl\Payment\Model\Config
     */
    private $config;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
     */
    private $checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    private $_logger;

    /**
     * @var PaymentHelper
     */
    private $paymentHelper;

    /**
     * @var QuoteRepository
     */
    private $quoteRepository;


    /**
     * @var OrderRepository
     */
    private $orderRepository;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Paynl\Payment\Model\Config $config
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,

        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        PaymentHelper $paymentHelper,
        QuoteRepository $quoteRepository,
        OrderRepository $orderRepository,\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement $quoteManagement,\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory
    )
    {
        //$this->config          = $config; // Pay.nl config helper
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->_logger         = $logger;
        $this->paymentHelper   = $paymentHelper;
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->quoteManagement = $quoteManagement;
        $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        try {

            if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST") {               
                $response_code = $_POST['response_code']; 

                if($response_code == 1)
                {
                    $order = $this->_getCheckoutSession()->getLastRealOrder();
                    $this->checkoutSession
                        ->setLastQuoteId($order->getQuoteId())
                        ->setLastSuccessQuoteId($order->getQuoteId())
                        ->clearHelperData();
                    if ($order) {
                        $this->checkoutSession->setLastOrderId($order->getId())
                                       ->setLastRealOrderId($order->getIncrementId())
                                       ->setLastOrderStatus('processing');
                    }            
                return $this->_redirect('checkout/onepage/success');

                }
                else{
                        $e = 'Payment Declined';
                        $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage($e, __('Something went wrong, please try again later'));
                        $this->_getCheckoutSession()->restoreQuote();
                        $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');

                }

            }

            /*$order = $this->_getCheckoutSession()->getLastRealOrder();
            $this->checkoutSession
                    ->setLastQuoteId($order->getQuoteId())
                    ->setLastSuccessQuoteId($order->getQuoteId())
                    ->clearHelperData();
                if ($order) {
                    $this->checkoutSession->setLastOrderId($order->getId())
                                       ->setLastRealOrderId($order->getIncrementId())
                                       ->setLastOrderStatus('processing');
                }            
                return $this->_redirect('checkout/onepage/success');*/
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage($e, __('Something went wrong, please try again later'));
            $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage($e, $e->getMessage());
            $this->_logger->critical($e);
            $this->_getCheckoutSession()->restoreQuote();
            $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Return checkout session object
     *
     * @return \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
     */
    protected function _getCheckoutSession()
    {
        return $this->checkoutSession;
    }
}
```

checkout_onepage_controller_success_action observer,

```
<?php
namespace Jed\Custompayment\Observer;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

class Custompayment implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry, \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager, \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession)
    {

        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    { 
        $orderId = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
        $base_url = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order') ->load($orderId[0]);
        $payment = $order->getPayment();


        $method = $payment->getMethodInstance();
        $methodTitle = $method->getTitle();

        $order_data= $order->getData();
        $status = $this->checkoutSession->getLastOrderStatus();

        if($status == 'processing' && $methodTitle == 'Custompayment'){
            $orderState = \Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PROCESSING;
            $order->setState($orderState)->setStatus(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PROCESSING);
            $order->save();
            return true;
        }
        else if($status == 'pending' && $methodTitle == 'Custompayment'){
          $increment_id = $order_data['increment_id'];
          $redirect = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http');
          $redirect->setRedirect($base_url.'custompayment/index/redirect/id/'.$increment_id.'');
          return;
        }
        else{
          return true;
        } 
    }
}
```